# Wordpress - Using a recursive fn to render the data from an API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, recursion, increment

I am setting up a new Wordpress site that utilizes the Spoonacular API.
I want to use a recursive function to render 50 items from the API, but I cannot figure out why my code is not calling the function again.
The result I am expecting to get, is that the 'report.txt' file that is created will display a constantly updating number up to the specified per_page number '50'.
The 'report.txt' file only displays the default number '1' instead of incrementing.
I am not sure if the function is being called again or not.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

functions.php

```
<?php

$apiKey = '123456789';

function get_ingredients_from_api() {

        $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/report.txt';
        
        $current_ingredient = ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'current_ingredient' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'current_ingredient' ] : 1 ;

        $ingredients = [];

        $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body(
            wp_remote_get('https://api.spoonacular.com/food/ingredients/autocomplete?query=appl&number=' . $current_ingredient . '&per_page=50&apiKey=' . $apiKey)
        );

        file_put_contents( $file, "Current Ingredient: " . $current_ingredient. "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);

        $results = json_decode($results);

        if ( ! is_array( $results ) || empty( $results ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        $current_ingredient = $current_ingredient + 1;

        wp_remote_post( admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_ingredients_from_api'), [
            'blocking' => false,
            'sslverify' => false,
            'body' => [
                'current_ingredient' => $current_ingredient
            ]
        ]);

    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ingredients_from_api', 'get_ingredients_from_api');
    add_action('wp_ajax_get_ingredients_from_api', 'get_ingredients_from_api');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that commenting out or removing the if statement from the code allows the function to run perfectly. I'm not sure how to keep the if statement and have the function run yet.